# The full pathname of a JDK installation for Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: java, linux, oracle, ubuntu, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to run `Oracle SQL Devloper` on Ubuntu with this command:

```
sh sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
```

Then I got this message:

> Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the
>   path will be stored in /home/aimad/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf

So I gave the path of jdk as the following:

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/

But then I got this message:

> Error: Java home /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386//bin/java is not a
>   JDK. Running SQL Developer under a JRE is not supported.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For me it was similar error. I solved it simply by inserting

```
SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

into ~/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf file.

Comment: @haidarvm and isn't it?

Comment: @Line I was did  with  /bin also  that's make error

Comment: Good answer, I had to remove the trailing slash to get mine working though

Comment: Thanks a ton. Setting JavaHome is also useful if you are facing this exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: libawt_xawt.so

Answer (score 15):

I Agree with szabozoltan's answer but there should be some explanation required for this:

```
SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

This one we need to keep in product.conf file. Inorder to open that file we need to type following command:

```
sudo gedit /home/abc/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf
```

After this, type the following command.

```
./sqldeveloper.sh
```

That's it, your SQL Developer
will be opened.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the /home/<user>/.sqldeveloper/<version>/product.conf takes precedence over the SQL_DEVELOPER_HOME/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf

Comment: I think this should be a comment to mentioned answer.

Answer (score 8):

You only have the Java JRE installed, you need to install the JDK in order for  Oracle SQL Devloper to work.

**TL;DR**

Install the JDK, type `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` in a terminal.

## Checking if JDK is Installed

To check if you have the JDK installed, type `aptitude search openjdk-7-jdk` in the terminal. If you see an `i` beside either package then it is installed. For example, I have the 64-bit JDK installed on my machine, this is the output.

```
$ aptitude search openjdk-7-jdk
i   openjdk-7-jdk                                   - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)                            
p   openjdk-7-jdk:i386                              - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)
```

If the package does not have an `i` beside it, then it is not installed.

## Installing JDK

To install in the JDK in ubuntu you need to install the package openjdk-7-jdk. Install by running `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` in a terminal.

### Setting JAVA_HOME

After installing the JDK you need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
You can see all the installed JDKs on your machine by running `update-java-alternatives -l`, choose the one you want to use and copy the third field, this field is the JAVA_HOME for that JDK.

For example, on my machine

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 1071 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

This means I only have one JDK installed, `java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`, and its JAVA_HOME is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`.

Next, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, in Bash I would set it by running this from the terminal:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

Check to make sure it was set correctly.

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
```

This will set JAVA_HOME for your current terminal session, to not have to worry about setting it again, you can add it to your `~/.bashrc` file.

## Running Oracle SQL Developer

Once the JDK is installed and the JAVA_HOME environment variable set, you can move into the sql developer directory and run the sqldeveloper.sh script.

```
$ cd sqldeveloper
$ ./sqldeveloper.sh
```

If sqldeveloper.sh is not executable run `chmod +x sqldeveloper.sh` and run the script again.

## Checking all Java packages

For completeness, you can check what Java packages you have installed by running `aptitude search openjdk-7`. If you have the JRE installed you will se an `i` beside a package that begins with `openjdk-7-jre`

```
$ aptitude search openjdk-7
p   openjdk-7-dbg                                   - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)        
p   openjdk-7-dbg:i386                              - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)        
p   openjdk-7-demo                                  - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)       
p   openjdk-7-demo:i386                             - Java runtime based on OpenJDK (demos and examples)       
p   openjdk-7-doc                                   - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) documentation              
i   openjdk-7-jdk                                   - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)                            
p   openjdk-7-jdk:i386                              - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)                            
i   openjdk-7-jre                                   - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT                  
p   openjdk-7-jre:i386                              - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT                  
i   openjdk-7-jre-headless                          - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)       
p   openjdk-7-jre-headless:i386                     - OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT (headless)       
i   openjdk-7-jre-lib                               - OpenJDK Java runtime (architecture independent libraries)
v   openjdk-7-jre-lib:i386                       -                                                          
p   openjdk-7-jre-zero                              - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark            
p   openjdk-7-jre-zero:i386                         - Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark            
p   openjdk-7-source                                - OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) source files               
p   uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-7                      - Java plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 7)                        
p   uwsgi-plugin-jvm-openjdk-7:i386                 - Java plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 7)                        
p   uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-7                    - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 7)                       
p   uwsgi-plugin-jwsgi-openjdk-7:i386               - JWSGI plugin for uWSGI (OpenJDK 7)
```

Comment: Whats the next step then ?

Comment: @VikasGoel I added a section on running the SQL Developer once the JDK has been installed. Basically, you have to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable and then run the sqldeveloper.sh script.

Comment: Why do you assume that OP does not have jdk installed? I would think otherwise from his question.

Comment: @Line The OP's error was _"Error: Java home /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386//bin/java is not a JDK. Running SQL Developer under a JRE is not supported."_

OpenJDK distribution has a JRE and a JDK build available, the OP had installed the JRE build, hence the error message.

In Ubuntu the different packages are openjdk-7-jre and openjdk-7-jdk

Comment: I still don't get how could you know what OP has installed. I'm asking, because it looks like it was JDK from the directory name, and I know from my experience that this error not necessarily means that you point to JRE instead of JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this by not adding slash as you did, so instead of

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/

type

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386

Answer (score 2):

Just type `/usr/java/default` and hit Enter if you use Oracle's JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert below one into ~/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf file.

```
SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by simply adding 'SetSkipJ2SDKCheck true'
to one of the below files.

```
/home/abc/.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.conf
/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
```

Comment: this does not look like _solution_, I wonder what is the reason here

Answer (score 1):

In my case *(Oracle SQL Developer* 4.1.3) it seems to be problem with Java version - when I point to **Java 8 JDK instead of 11**, it started working immediately.

Comment: If you want to use Java 11, use SQL Developer v19.2, not version 4.1.3, which was released before Java 11 existed...

Answer (score 1):

I've faced with similar issue. Tried published recommendations but unsuccessfully. Possible the reason I'm using `sdkman` to manage java versions, may be something with permissions because of Mac OS.

For Mac user it is important try manage configuration:

- try `SetJavaHome {{path to your java}}` in ~/.sqldeveloper/{{sql-dev-version}}/product.conf

this step could help if you are using jdk installed by brew following default path.

If you've installed openjdk with `sdkman` path to java will be like `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/{{java-version}}` and this path needs to be mapped on default expectations with aliases.

I did not have information about the default path, so it needs to find executable file:

- start sqldeveloper (to make shown `error message`);
- in terminal try `ps ux | grep sql` - it will help you to detect executable file location `sqldeveloper.sh`;
- open the file with text editor:

  - remove or comment block that tries to get java from default location `/usr/libexec/java_home`;
  - find line with `export JAVA_HOME=$TMP_PATH` and replace path with your path to java home or simply remove line if `JAVA_HOME` was specified in OS settings.

Answer (score 0):

In newer version I needed to extend the path in

```
/Users/{{yourUsername}}/.sqldeveloper/21.2.1/product.conf

SetJavaHome /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.13.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
 apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
 apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
 apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
 add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
 apt-get update
 apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```