# Error on running sql developer in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sql, oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have looked up for this problem in stackoverflow.
I found the question raised in the following link similar to mine and i tried doing what was mentioned in it but that doesn't seem to be working for me.
[The full pathname of a JDK installation for Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22158923/the-full-pathname-of-a-jdk-installation-for-oracle-sql-developer)

I have tried adding the path in the product.conf file but this still gives error. this is what i am getting

```
./sqldeveloper.sh 

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 2005, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /home/nithinchandranp/.sqldeveloper/18.3.0/product.conf
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 
Error: Java home /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 is not a JDK,
either jre/bin/java OR lib/tools.jar OR lib/dt.jar is missing.
Running SQL Developer under a JRE is not supported.

If this Java VM is actually a full JDK installation, add
'SetSkipJ2SDKCheck true' to one of the following files.
Otherwise specify a different Java JDK location with a
SetJavaHome directive in one of the following files:
  /home/nithinchandranp/.sqldeveloper/18.3.0/product.conf
  /home/nithinchandranp/SQL Developer/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
```

Can someone please help me with this issue.
thank you.

Comment: Get Oracle Java JDK 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We require JDK 8, and only support Oracle Java.

Support for open JDK 11 is planned for later next year.